# DotNetOpenID Programmatic Login

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I am using Dotnetopenid for my openid solution, everything is fine when using the built-in user control, but when I want to implement it programmaticaly, like the below code,

```
openid.Response.GetExtension<DotNetOpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration.ClaimsResponse>();
```

is always null.
any idea?

```
    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = createRelyingParty();
    if (openid.Response != null) {
        switch (openid.Response.Status) {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                // This is where you would look for any OpenID extension responses included
                // in the authentication assertion.
                // var extension = openid.Response.GetExtension<SomeExtensionResponseType>();

                // Use FormsAuthentication to tell ASP.NET that the user is now logged in,
                // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username.
                State.ProfileFields = openid.Response.GetExtension<DotNetOpenId.Extensions.SimpleRegistration.ClaimsResponse>();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(openid.Response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                break;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getting help from [Andrew](http://blog.nerdbank.net)

I've missed to add extension to my request before redirecting to provider.
( this step is not coded in sample files )

to do this, after creating the request object do like this:

```
  Dim request As IAuthenticationRequest = openid.CreateRequest(openid_identifier.Text)
        ' This is where you would add any OpenID extensions you wanted
        ' to include in the authentication request.
        ' request.AddExtension(someExtensionRequestInstance);
        Dim myclaim As New ClaimsRequest

        With myclaim
            .BirthDate = DemandLevel.Request
            .Country = DemandLevel.Request
            .Email = DemandLevel.Request
            .FullName = DemandLevel.Request
            .Gender = DemandLevel.Request
            .Language = DemandLevel.Request
            .Nickname = DemandLevel.Request
            .PostalCode = DemandLevel.Request
            .TimeZone = DemandLevel.Request

        End With


        request.AddExtension(myclaim)









        ' Send your visitor to their Provider for authentication.
        request.RedirectToProvider()
```

code is in vb.net

Comment: Can you please point to some step by step instructions of implementing DotNetOpenId in MVC. I am a beginner with MVC and OpenId.

Comment: @Picflight you can check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933884/request-for-tutorial-to-add-openid-support-to-nerddinner-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Noted to be fixed and made clearer in next release.